# ColdFusion 10 Update 14 Issue

Tags: java, coldfusion

I installed the update 14 for CF 10 today and updated the wsconfig.  Since then, my site has not come back up.  I noticed that a new folder (2) was created in the wsconfig folder.  The following error is returned when trying to view any ColdFusion page on the server.

> Service Temporary Unavailable!
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>       Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.32 ()

This is appearing in the error log.

```
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
> com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:86) at
> com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:161)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.<init>(Z)V at
> com.adobe.coldfusion.launcher.ServerConfigParser.parse(ServerConfigParser.java:55)
> at com.adobe.coldfusion.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:193) ... 6
> more
```

Any idea what steps I can take to resolve this issue?  Is there anyway to undo the update?

Comment: Did you recreate the connector? Because, in that case, the older folder should be replaced by the new folder. There shouldn't be an extra entry. Remove all the connectors and recreate them.

Moreover, the issues seems to be with the applying of update. Can you check the update log for confirmation?

Comment: Yes.  I deleted all configurations and recreated them.  The website was trying to find the isapi_redirector in the "2" folder which was deleted when I deleted the configs.  I restarted the website and got the same exact message I got prior to making the change.

Comment: As I said, the older folder should be replaced by the new folder after connector recreation. After you create the connector, it should only be looking for the new isapi_redirect.dll location.


Can you check the update log for any errors or warning?

Comment: Actually the log file does show that the installation was unsuccessful.  Since I cannot get the CF Admin to run, is there another way to manually install the update?

Comment: You need to manually uninstall the update first. Refer to http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-hotfix-installation-guide. After that, try the following

1. Download the update from http://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/coldfusion/hotfix_014.jar?
2. Copy the jar file to {cf_install}\jre\bin\.
3. Launch Command prompt as Administrator.
4. Browse to the location mentioned in Step 2 and type this command “java –jar hotfix_014.jar”
5. It will launch the update window. Follow the on screen instructions.